# Questions in Veach path-space formulation

Tags: pathtracing

http://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/veach_thesis/chapter8.ps

In chapter 8 of his thesis which he talks about the three-point form of the transport equations, equation (8.1) in particular, it seems the integrand will expand into something that contains a $\cos^2(\theta_i^\prime)$ term. One of the cosine terms comes from the $G$, and the other one comes the BSDF $f_s$ which is defined with respect to the projected solid angle.

When I look at PBRT V3's implementation, BSDF is defined upon solid angle. However, the geometry term $G$ is the same as Veach's.

```cpp
Spectrum G(const Scene &scene, Sampler &sampler, const Vertex &v0,
           const Vertex &v1) {
    Vector3f d = v0.p() - v1.p();
    Float g = 1 / d.LengthSquared();
    d *= std::sqrt(g);
    if (v0.IsOnSurface()) g *= AbsDot(v0.ns(), d);
    if (v1.IsOnSurface()) g *= AbsDot(v1.ns(), d);
    VisibilityTester vis(v0.GetInteraction(), v1.GetInteraction());
    return g * vis.Tr(scene, sampler);
}
```

This implies there is only one $\cos(\theta_i^\prime)$ term. Am I missing something?

Comment: Where are you getting this $\cos^2(\theta_i')$ from? There is only one $\cos(\theta_i')$ and $\cos(\theta_o)$ per path segment. If the BSDF is defined with respect to solid angle then the extra cosine is bundled with the geometry term, which seems to be the case for PBRT.

Comment: The PBRT's implementation indeed contains only one consine term. However, in Veach's paper, the BSDF is defined with respect to projected solid angle (http://graphics.stanford.edu/papers/veach_thesis/chapter3.ps equation 3.12), and the geometry term in chapter 8 contains one extra consine term.

Comment: Cos in renderequation cancels it out?

Comment: @joojaa Can you elaborate?